# sort list of strings based on the index of particular substring

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

How can I sort a list of sentences like this:

```
_list = ["i want to buy a car", 
         "never buy a carpet", 
         "i need to buy more stuff", 
         "i don't want to buy it"]
```

based on a word that precedes / follows a word "buy"?

One way would be to create additional list, store all words that precede / follow the word "buy" and then sort both lists based on a key from a new list. But is there a way to do it without creating additional list?

Comment: Why do you need to create an extra list? You can create them within the `key` function itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need any extra lists. You can call `list_.sort` with a `key=callback`:

```
def foo(x):
    l = x.lower().split()
    return l[l.index('buy') - 1]

list_.sort(key=foo)
# ['never buy a carpet', 'i want to buy a car', 'i need to buy more, ...]
```

This assumes the word `buy` exists in each string and that it is *not* the first word in the string. Additional checks may need to be made, and you can modify `foo` for that. The function `foo` returns the word that precedes `buy`, based on which the list is to be sorted.

Comment: Thanx for the answer.

Comment: OK,I got it now.I need to print latter.